# How can i "merge" these two regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm learning regular expression, so please go easy with me!

Username is considered valid when **does not start with `_`** (underscore) and if contains **only word characters** (letters, digits and underscore itself):

```php
namespace Gremo\ExtraValidationBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class UsernameValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // Violation if username starts with underscore
        if (preg_match('/^_', $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
            return;
        }

        // Violation if username does not contain all word characters
        if (!preg_match('/^\w+$/', $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to **merge them in one regular expression**, i've tried the following:

```php
^_+[^\w]+$
```

To be read as: *add a violation if starts with an underscore (eventually more than one) and if at least one character following is not allowed (not a letter, digit or underscore)*. Does not work with "_test", for example.

Can you help me to understand where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a negative lookahead assertion to your 2nd regex:

```
^(?!_)\w+$
```

Which now means, try to match the entire string and not any part of it. The string must not begin with an underscore and can have one or more of word characters.

[**See it work**](http://www.rubular.com/r/4CaJPsJEBu)

Comment: Looks good, but I can't get the "negative lookahead" thing. Can you point me to a simple explanation on how it works?

Comment: Another question if you dont mind, which part of the regex specifies the "try to match the entire string and not any part of it" ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). `^_+[^\w]+$` will only match if it starts with one or more underscores *and* **all** subsequent characters are non-word characters. You need to match if it starts with an underscore *or* **any** character is a non-word character.

I think it's simpler, in this case, to focus on the valid usernames: they start with a word character other than an underscore, and all remaining characters are word characters. In other words, valid usernames are described by the pattern `^[^\W_]\w*$`. So, you can write:

```
if (! preg_match('/^[^\W_]\w*$/', $value, $matches)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is this:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
```

you just wanted the `\w` group (which includes the underscore) but without the underscore, so `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is equivalent to `\w` but without the underscore.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` was my first thought as well, but then I consulted the documentation, which says that `\w` is locale-sensitive. It explicitly mentions `[^\W_]` as meaning "word character other than underscore". (See [http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).)

Answer (score 0):

There are of course, many different ways of doing this. I'd probably look at going with something along the lines of `/^(?!_)[\w\d_]+/$`.

The `[\w\d_]+` part combined with the anchors (^ and $), essentially assert that the entire string only consist of those characters. The (?!_) part is a negative lookahead assertion. It means check the next character isn't an underscore. Since it's right next to the ^ anchor, this ensures the first character isn't an underscore.

Comment: FYI, the `\d` and `_` in your regex are redundant; `\w` already matches digits and underscores as well as letters.

Comment: Indeed, it's been a long day.